# Стили графического интерфейса приложения в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qstyle, qstylefactory

В стандартном редакторе *Qt Designer* есть стандартные шаблоны `Fusion`, `Windows`.

Есть ли какие-то еще шаблоны кроме них?
Если есть, то как их установить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы узнать, какие стили установлены в системе, просто вызовите `QStyleFactory.keys()`.

```
print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())
```

Обратите внимание, что не все стили доступны для каждой системы. 
Обычно доступны `Fusion` и `Windows` что означает,
что если вы попытаетесь получить доступ к стилю `macintosh`, а он не установлен,
вместо него будет использован запасной стиль.

---

> void QApplication::[**setStyle(QStyle style)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle)
>
> Устанавливает стиль графического интерфейса приложения. 
> Право собственности на объект стиля передается `QApplication`.

> QStyle *QApplication::[**setStyle(const QString &style)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle-1)
>
> Запрашивает объект `QStyle` для стиля из `QStyleFactory`.
> Строка должна быть одной из `QStyleFactory::keys()`,
> обычно одной из "windows", "windowsvista", "fusion" или "macintosh".  
> Имена стилей нечувствительны к регистру.
>
> Возвращает nullptr, если передан неизвестный стиль,
> в противном случае возвращаемый объект `QStyle` устанавливается как стиль
> графического интерфейса приложения.
>
> Предупреждение: Чтобы убедиться, что стиль приложения установлен правильно,
> лучше всего, если это возможно, вызывать эту функцию до конструктора `QApplication`.
>
> `QStyle *QApplication::style()`
> Возвращает объект стиля приложения.

---

> [**Класс QStyleFactory**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html) создает объекты `QStyle`.
>
> [**Класс QStyle**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) — это абстрактный базовый класс, который инкапсулирует
> внешний вид графического интерфейса.
>
> `QStyleFactory` создает объект `QStyle`, используя функцию [**create()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html#create) и ключ, идентифицирующий стиль.
>
> Стили либо встроены, либо динамически загружаются из плагина стиля (см. [**QStylePlugin**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleplugin.html)).

---

[**Создание пользовательского стиля**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html#creating-a-custom-style)

Вы можете создать индивидуальный внешний вид своего приложения,
создав собственный стиль. 
Существует два подхода к созданию собственного стиля. 
`При статическом подходе` вы либо выбираете существующий класс `QStyle`,
создаете для него подкласс и переопределяете виртуальные функции для обеспечения
пользовательского поведения, либо создаете целый класс `QStyle` с нуля.

`При динамическом подходе` вы изменяете поведение вашего системного стиля
во время выполнения.

Статический подход описан ниже. 
Динамический подход описан в [**QProxyStyle**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproxystyle.html).

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox,
    QStyleFactory)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
    

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(410, 340)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.rdbPlastique = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbPlastique.setObjectName("rdbPlastique")
        self.bgrpRadio = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)
        self.bgrpRadio.setObjectName("bgrpRadio")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbPlastique)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbPlastique, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rdbGTK = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbGTK.setObjectName("rdbGTK")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbGTK)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbGTK, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rdbMacintosh = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbMacintosh.setObjectName("rdbMacintosh")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbMacintosh)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbMacintosh, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.rdbWindowsXP = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbWindowsXP.setObjectName("rdbWindowsXP")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbWindowsXP)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbWindowsXP, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.rdbWindows = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbWindows.setObjectName("rdbWindows")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbWindows)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbWindows, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.rdbWindowsVista = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbWindowsVista.setObjectName("rdbWindowsVista")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbWindowsVista)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbWindowsVista, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.rdbFusion = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbFusion.setObjectName("rdbFusion")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbFusion)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbFusion, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.rdbCDE = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbCDE.setObjectName("rdbCDE")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbCDE)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbCDE, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.rdbCleanLooks = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbCleanLooks.setObjectName("rdbCleanLooks")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbCleanLooks)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbCleanLooks, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rdbMotif = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.rdbMotif.setObjectName("rdbMotif")
        self.bgrpRadio.addButton(self.rdbMotif)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.rdbMotif, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.btnMessageBox = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnMessageBox.setObjectName("btnMessageBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.btnMessageBox, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lblVersion = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblVersion.setObjectName("lblVersion")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lblVersion, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 410, 36))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "QWindowsStyle"))
        self.rdbPlastique.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "plastique"))
        self.rdbGTK.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "gtk"))
        self.rdbMacintosh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "macintosh"))
        self.rdbWindowsXP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "windowsxp"))
        self.rdbWindows.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "windows"))
        self.rdbWindowsVista.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "windowsvista"))
        self.rdbFusion.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "fusion"))
        self.rdbCDE.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "cde"))
        self.rdbCleanLooks.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "cleanlooks"))
        self.rdbMotif.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "motif"))
        self.btnMessageBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "MessageBox"))
        self.lblVersion.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("QMessageBox Style Test")
        self.comboBox.addItems(['Выберите  COM-порт', 'com1', 'com2', 'com3',])
        
        verString = 'PyQt version: ' + QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR + '\n'
        verString += 'Qt version__: ' + QtCore.qVersion()
        self.lblVersion.setText(verString)
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_bgrpRadio_buttonClicked(self, button):
        # имя стиля представляет собой строчную версию имени объекта с удаленным 'rdb'
        style_name = self.bgrpRadio.checkedButton().objectName()
        style_name = style_name.replace('rdb', '').lower()
        print(style_name)
        
        app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create(style_name))                         # !!!
        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_btnMessageBox_clicked(self):
        buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(
            None, 'Exit', "Quit Program?",
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
            
            
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    
    print(f'\nQStyleFactory.keys(): \n    {QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys()}\n') # !!!
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]